# Chern's Lectures on Differential Geometry, 5.2, torsion free connection and curvature tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature, geodesic, connections

Chern's proof of Theorem 2.3 seems to be extremely confusing for me since:

(1) Since ${\alpha^{i}}$ has itself formed a coordinate, why t is necessary to describe how the one forms change?

(2) Why when $\alpha^{k}$ is constant the one - forms $\theta^{i}$ and $\theta^{i}_{j}$ are "restricted" to the curve $\alpha^{i}t$? Shouldn't it be restricted to $\alpha^{k}t$?

(3) How is (2.20) derived? It is correct on the curve $\alpha^{i}t$ but it does not seem to be obvious on other geodesic curves.

Thanks!

[Chern's proof: page one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWvj3.png)

[Chern's proof: page two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwHCC.png)

[Chern's proof: page three](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLONm.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).